# MD5 Checksum cannot be null

Tags: ros, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I start up a subscriber on my android device to listen to a publisher running on my computer. I receive the following error after my subscriber has been created and executed:

E/SubscriberHandshakeHandler(3885): Subscriber handshake failed: Incoming MD5 checksum cannot be null.

I believe it occurs on receipt of the first message, but I am not sure.

I am running jellybean on the tablet and groovy on the pc. They are connected over a wifi connection with the roscore running on the pc.

Any help is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55310/md5-checksum-cannot-be-null/) by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2013-02-19**:
Are you using the latest rosjava? How is the publisher written? In Java as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. I using a publisher with a custom-built message that was essentially serialized to a string, but still a custom-message in name. My subscriber was looking for std_msgs/String, but not receiving any, so the checksum was off.

Sorry for the confusion.

-Steve

---

Originally posted by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) with karma: 74 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0